# Lubuntu 17.04 xrdp. Can connect from network. No remote access

Tags: lubuntu, remote-desktop, remote, xrdp

I have followed several different "solutions" on this to no avail.

help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp
tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-
https://wademurray.com/2014/xrdp-remote-desktop-on-lubuntu-14-04/

to name a few.

I admit I am new to Linux.  Any help would be appreciated. Connecting from Windows Remote Desktop. Again, this works fine when I'm on the same network but what I need is remote access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following step by step guide (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10365). This one is for Lubuntu 16.10 but should be valid for Lubuntu 17.04.

In short,

1. install the xrdp package by issuing the following command 
   **sudo apt-get install xrdp**
2. From command line, issue the following command 
   **echo "lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE" >~/.xsession**
3. Optional - restart your machine and give it a try

Hope this help 
Till next time 
See ya